# Unexpected output of Django's "makemessages" with "blocktrans" and "trans"

Tags: django, internationalization, django-templates

I have two files with equal strings to translate, in the first file
with "trans" and in the second file with "blocktrans" and a plural form:

```
a.html:
{% trans 'My string' %}

b.html:
{% blocktrans count counter=mylist|length %}My string{% plural %}My strings{% endblocktrans %}
```

and when I run "django-admin.py makemessages -l de" I get

```
django.po
#: templates/a.html:108
#: templates/b.html:3
msgid "My string"
msgstr ""
```

and not as I'd expect

```
django.po
#: templates/a.html:108
#: templates/b.html:3
msgid "My string"
msgid_plural "My strings"
msgstr[0] ""
msgstr[1] ""
```

I can reproduce this for similar structures in other files.
"blocktrans" strings that don't have "trans" equivalents in other
files correctly produce entries with plural forms in the .po file.
What's going wrong here?

Any help would be greatly appreciated...

Comment: I have [filed a bug report](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/17375) for my problem...